# Does Expo exposes a quit lifecycle method to handle the situation where an app is killed?

Tags: react-native, expo, lifecycle, kill

I've written a navigation Expo app (for rural roads) that uses a TaskManager to register the user's position in background.

I was wondering if Expo exposes any lifecycle method to handle when the app is suddenly killed in the background, for instance, when the user decided do rapidly discard the app.

Comment: I have ever searched for the result. But it seems no way. Even use native code it's hard to notify when force closed by the user.

Comment: That's why I stopped using expo before, and use native instead since my apps required native SDKs most of the time. You can't use background location in Expo right now as far as I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try [bare workflow](https://docs.expo.io/bare/exploring-bare-workflow/) and do that natively.
I'm not sure that's really possible to do though.